# Ball contained in the union of disjoint open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space, and let $B(x, r) := \{y \in M : d(x, y) \leq r\}$ be the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an arbitrary family of *disjoint* and *open* subsets of $M$. Suppose that $$B(x, r) \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i,$$ for some $x \in M$ and $r > 0$. Can we then conclude that $B(x, r) \subseteq U_i$ for some fixed $i \in I$? My intuition is telling me that this result is true, but I'm struggling to find an elegant proof. Also, if the result is not true, then maybe it's only true for finite or countable unions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $B(0,\sqrt3)$ is a closed ball in $\Bbb Q$ that is contained in the union of the disjoint open sets $(\leftarrow,\sqrt2)$ and $(\sqrt2,\to)$ but not contained in either of them. It will be true if $B(x,r)$ is connected, however.

Comment: Thanks! Clearly, my assumptions were too general. I posted a new question under more restrictive assumptions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3845695/829063)

Comment: @dualspace89: You’re welcome; I’ll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Take $M=[0,1] \bigcup [2,3]$ endowed with the usual metric from $\mathbb{R}$, $U_1=[0,1]$ and $U_2=[2,3]$. Then $B(1,2) \subset U_1 \bigcup U_2$ but $B(1,2)$ is neither in $U_1$ nor in $U_2$.

(Note that $B(1,2)=[0,1] \bigcup [2,3]$ here)

Comment: Thanks! Clearly, my assumptions were too general. I posted a new question under more restrictive assumptions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3845695/829063)