# Ball contained in the union of disjoint open sets in a normed finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space with norm $\|\cdot\|$, and let $B(x, r) := \{y \in X : \|x - y\| \leq r\}$ be the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an arbitrary family of *disjoint* and *open* subsets of $X$. Suppose that $$B(x, r) \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i,$$ for some $x \in X$ and $r > 0$.

Is there a simple and elegant proof that $B(x, r) \subseteq U_i$ for some fixed $i \in I$? Ideally, I would like a direct proof that does not rely on connectedness arguments. Thanks!

Comment: You’ll need to specify something about the scalar field: otherwise $\Bbb Q$ as a one-dimensional space over itself is a counterexample.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I can assume that the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You’re welcome. $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ should both work, though I doubt that you can avoid connectedness entirely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If we take a non-connected closed subset of $X$ instead of $B(x,r)$, then it is definitely wrong. Thus we cannot avoid connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid connectedness. See 2. below.

Let $X$ be an *arbritrary topological space* and $M \subset X$.

1. Let $M$ be a connected subspace of $X$  and $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of disjoint and open subsets of $X$. If $M  \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$, then $M \subseteq U_j$ for some fixed $j \in I$.

In fact, there exists $j \in I$ such that $M \cap U_j \ne \emptyset$. Let $V_j =  \bigcup_{i \in I, i \ne j} U_i$. Then $M \cap U_j, M \cap V_j$ are disjoint open subsets of $M$ which cover $M$. Since $M \cap U_j \ne \emptyset$, we must have $M \cap V_j = \emptyset$. Thus $M \subset U_j$.

2. Let $X$ be normal and $M$ be closed in $X$. Assume that for each family $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of disjoint and open subsets of $X$ such that $M  \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ there exists $j \in I$ such that $M \subseteq U_j$. Then $M$ is a connected subspace of $X$.

Assume $M$ is not connected. Then there exist disjoint non-empty closed subsets $C_1, C_2$ of $M$ such that $M = C_1 \cup C_2$. Both $C_i$ are closed in $X$ since $M$ is closed in $X$. The Urysohn theorem gives us disjoint open subsets $U_1, U_2$ of $X$ such that $C_i \subseteq U_i$. Hence $M \subset U_1 \cup U_2$. Our assumption shows that $M$ is contained in some $U_i$, w.l.o.g in in $U_1$. Thus $M \cap U_2 = \emptyset$ which implies that $C_2 = M \cap C_2 = \emptyset$, a contradiction.